# How can i make a console interface for my android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, console

I have an app in android studio written in java. I was wondering if i could have it run in a console style interface and if i need to use one of the templates available in android studio or how exactly i go about this. This is my first time programming a app in java (without tutorials) and coming from python i am a little confused. Any help is greatly appreciated.

````
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        int points = 0;
        int tries = 3;
        while(true){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  //System.in is a standard input stream
            System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
            String str = sc.next();   //reads string before the space
            int len = str.length();
            points = points + len;
            if(list.contains(str)) {
                System.out.println("You already said that word -1 try");
                tries = tries - 1;
                points = points - len;
                if(tries == 0){
                    System.out.println("Game Over");
                    System.out.println("You had" + points + "points left");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            list.add(str);
            System.out.println("Do not say " + str + " again");
            System.out.println("You have " + points + " points left");
            System.out.println("You have " + tries + "tries left");
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: "I was wondering if i could have it run in a console style interface" -- no, at least in terms of what you are expecting from that code. Android is not a desktop operating system with a terminal or other form of console, the way Windows, macOS, and Linux are. "This is my first time programming a app in java" -- Java is a programming language. You also need to learn how to write Android apps. There are plenty of educational resources on Android app development. [Here is a free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/), for example.

Comment: Do the coding in Java in an IDE like Netbeans https://netbeans.apache.org/ (i reccomend using Maven instead of Gradle there, less headaches), then when you're done copy it to the Android project. This assuming what you want to do doesn't require Android APIs, Android runs whole apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the link! I ended up just making a gui with android studio and i am aware java is a programming language I simply just dont know really anything about it.